# Trying to convert all columns that are objects to strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

There are quite a few questions that deal with converting a specific column or all columns, but not a specific few columns where the `dtype` is something specific. Now if I got data with some of the columns being `object`s, I would like to see those specific columns cast into strings.

I think I am currently doing something like:

```
for column in calls.columns:
    if calls[column].dtype == 'object':
        calls[column] = calls[column].astype(str)
```

But I am looking for a more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the pandas version you have, "object" is the string type.

That said, you could do this:

```
df.astype({col: str for col in df.select_dtypes('object').columns})
```

Or equivalent:

```
df.astype({col: str for col, dtype in df.dtypes.items() if dtype=='object'})
```

Answer (score 2):

you might use the following code:

```
calls[calls.select_dtypes(include='object').columns] = calls.select_dtypes(include='object').astype(dtype='category')
```